I only ever get the value MS= from ms graph, without the verification value
I am currently trying to retrieve the tenant´s domain settings via ms graph.
One setting is the TXT verification entry like MS=<some-value>.
However, I only ever get the value MS= from ms graph, without the verification value.
Do I have to do something different in this case?
Approved permissions:

Domain.Read.All
Domain.ReadWrite.All

The http-get call I use:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/domains/<domain>/verificationDnsRecords

The response from the ms graph api:
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#domainDnsRecords",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.domainDnsTxtRecord",
            "id": "<some-id>",
            "isOptional": false,
            "label": "<domain>",
            "recordType": "Txt",
            "supportedService": "Email",
            "ttl": 3600,
            "text": "MS="
        }
    ]
}


where you check the TXT record?  check here https://admin.cloud.microsoft/?#/Domains  if TXT records already been done.

From an MS Graph standpoint, this is by design. While the Microsoft Graph API allows you to pull DNS records of a domain, the verification value is not returned by the API for security reasons as it could potentially be misused without legitimate ownership leading to security risks. This implies that you cannot retrieve the TXT verification record programmatically via the API.
